# Refinement panel with hierarchy of managed metadata in SharePoint 2013

Tags: managed-metadata, sharepoint-server, refinement-panel

I'm implementing managed metadata in a SharePoint 2013 on premise environment. 
This environment will have a lot of document libraries that make use of content types. In these content types, a site column (connected to the managed metadata) 'Department' will be implemented.

In the search center, i configured this field as a refiner to let the user filter all documents/items by this department field (term). Now every departement also has a kind of 'subdepartment' (subterm).
What I want to achieve is that if a user selects a 'root'-department term (for example IT), also the documents that are tagged with the child  term (for example IT-functional) will be shown in the search results.

I know it's possible to achieve this in a content query webpart (include child terms) so I hope this is possible in the search center too.

Anyone knows how to configure this or get this implemented? It would be a huge improvement!
I already searched the internet but nothing worked for me :(

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Deefken

Comment: Does anyone has any answer on this? This should be pretty out of the box or straight forward to solve this :(

Comment: I found you can use the taxonomy refinement panel and get it 'connected' to your refinements panel, but as of today, i didn't get this work. I know it should be that region I have to search for a solution on this.

Comment: Is there something new? Facing the same problem. How to get the taxonomy refinement panel to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to implement or buy a custom display template for your managed metadata refiner. This would allow you to modify the query sent to the search results webpart when a parent term is clicked to include those results tagged with its children instead of just with it alone (using the {Term.IDWithChildren} variable)

To avoid confusing users, you may want to expose the tag hierarchy in the refiner or result item display templates so they understand the parent/child relationship.